# microsoft vscode - change UI text color

Tags: visual-studio-code

this is regarding Microsoft Visual Studio Code text editor - not Visual Studio 2015 IDE.

I am using light Color Theme - white background and dark text, but these themes set color to the UI also. 
For example, file explorer has light grey text on slightly lighter grey background.
Please help the (almost) blind person but I have a hard time to see this text.

- How to change the this theme?
- Where it the "theme" file?
- What to change in this file to set the color of text to BLACK `#000`

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

With help from Microsoft, see github issue:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6065
scroll down to the last entry. The file workbench.main.css will allow you to customize the UI the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/themes) to know how to build custom themes for vscode.

Themes descriptions are stored in *Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\theme-xxx* folder. Edit the xxx.tmTheme to customize colors.