# Color coding keywords in Microsoft Visual Studio -[Newbie level]

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-c++

I'm pretty new to Microsoft Visual Studio but have played around with Visual Studio Code before. I'm thinking of integrating my work with Microsoft Azure so looking to start getting a handle with MVS instead.

However, one small thing that drives me bananas is that keywords like functions and variables aren't color coded in MVS. I tried changing the theme but no bueno. I see online that there are options to [make custom color themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006921/microsoft-vscode-change-ui-text-color) but I'm not looking to make a huge customization, just wanted something smart, simple, and out of the box.

Is there any quick way to improve color coding in MVS?

[Link to the difference I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt9N5.png)

Comment: The search keywords you're looking for are *Visual Studio syntax highlighting*.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=StanislavKuzmichArtStea1th.EnhancedSyntaxHighlighting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to Ken White I found what I was looking for: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.SyntaxHighlightingPack

Consider this question closed. (I can't accept my own answer yet)

Edit: Couldn't get it to work after installing the tool pack so pointers would be nice, but it's gotten too technical at this point.